# Autopilot problem formulation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, optimization, control-theory

Let us suppose we have a very simple particle movement simulation:

$\dot{x}(t) = f(t,F(t))$

where ***F*** is applied force. Integrating over ***t*** and ***F*** we can get the final position of the object.

Now, at some point ***t'*** I need the object to be located at ***x'*** and move with the speed $\dot{x'}$. I need to find such ***F(t)*** that the condition meets. Moreover, I may need to minimize either time or amount of energy spent.

What will be the definition of the problem? What methods can I use to solve it? What branches of mathematics/engineering deal with such problems?

Comment: This looks like a dynamical system to me.  If you're lucky, it will be a linear dynamical system.  There are lectures from Stephen Boyd from Stanford on Linear Dynamical Systems on Youtube.

Answer (score 1):

Optimal control or more generally calculus of variation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_control